# Rust sets that can create a clone in O(1) and can be updated separately

Tags: rust, data-structures

I have a set of numbers,  set1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
and I want to create a clone (copy) of set1 in O(1).
I know I can do this using Rc, Box.
Assume this copy is set2.

I also want to update set1 and set2 separately.
For example

```
set1.insert(10);
set2.insert(6);
```

so at the end of the day, I will have

```
set1 = {1,2,3,4,5,10}
set2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Elements in the set will not be removed or updated,
I've tried a lot of methods, but it seems at some point there will be an O(n) operation that clone all elements.

Comment: *"I know I can do this using Rc, Box"* - I think you are mistaken. `Rc` doesn't copy it, it only creates a second reference to the same set. `Box` does copy it, but it isn't `O(1)`; it's `O(n)`. The act of copying `n` elements is bound to `O(n)`, unless you re-use some of the original data it simply isn't possible to duplicate a set in `O(1)`.

Comment: Is one of these what you're looking for? https://crates.io/crates/immutable-avl, https://crates.io/crates/immutable-chunkmap, https://crates.io/crates/hash-trie

Comment: Such a data structure is not that hard to implement, but only if you clone `O(1)` times. The idea is that once you've cloned a set, you never modify it again. Instead, you share it immutably among all the other copies; furthermore, when you add or delete an entry from a "copy", you keep track of what has been added (resp. deleted) in a separate set. Clone and update are in `O(1)`, but with 2 copies you end up with 5 actual sets, so there is a considerable overhead.

Comment: This could be done with a custom set type that can optionally own a "parent" `Arc` of its same type, but then you have to do N lookups (for each ancestor) internally for every one operation on the set.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I don't think avl trees are O(1) update.

Comment: @jthulhu Yeah, true, they are O(log(n)). It's still an improvement over O(n), but not as good as O(1).

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/ppar and https://crates.io/crates/chainmap are also related.

Comment: There are a bunch of options to consider listed here: https://crates.io/keywords/immutable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clone a data structure containing `n` elements so that the new structure has its own copy of the original elements must take at least `O(n)` time complexity. Even if cloning is just copying a contiguous block of memory, it's fast but it's still `O(n)`.

Since your requirement doesn't involve updating the "cloned" data, you can instead share it using `Rc` or `Arc`:

```
use std::{collections::HashSet, hash::Hash, cmp::Eq, rc::Rc};

pub struct PartiallySharedHashSet<T> {
    shared: Rc<HashSet<T>>,
    own: HashSet<T>,
}

impl<T: Hash + Eq> PartiallySharedHashSet<T> {
    pub fn new(shared: Rc<HashSet<T>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            shared,
            own: HashSet::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, item: T) -> bool {
        if self.shared.contains(&item) {
            false
        } else {
            self.own.insert(item)
        }
    }

    pub fn contains(&self, item: &T) -> bool {
        self.own.contains(item) || self.shared.contains(item)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fn main() {
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    set.insert(1);
    let set = Rc::new(set);

    let mut set1 = PartiallySharedHashSet::new(set.clone());
    set1.insert(2);
    let mut set2 = PartiallySharedHashSet::new(set);
    set2.insert(3);

    assert!(set1.contains(&1));
    assert!(set1.contains(&2));
    assert!(!set1.contains(&3));

    assert!(set2.contains(&1));
    assert!(!set2.contains(&2));
    assert!(set2.contains(&3));
}
```

Comment: FWIW you can create a "copy" in O(1), but that means your "update" will be in logarithmic time. And you might have higher constant factors as well. That's what persistent datastructures will give you.

Comment: @Masklinn if it's in O(1) time then it's, as you put it, a "copy" not a _copy_.

Comment: Copy's in the eye of the beholder, if if you have one structure, and from that you create a second structure whose alterations can't affect the first, then for all intents and purposes you have a copy. Trivial copying and structural sharing are advantages of functional data structures.

Comment: You can improve the operations supported by the datastructure (ie. add a `remove` method) by also keeping a set of deleted items. When you check containment, it should be either in the owned set, or (in the shared set but not in the deleted items set). Similarly, when you add an item, you also remove it from the deleted items set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I realized that there are some flaws in my description. Since the shared elements are immutable once a shared set is created, I am actually looking for a way to utilize a pointer or reference, rather than a strict 'clone'. Your proposed solution solved my question perfectly!